# Get in the Main Activity data from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcast

I readed a lot of similar questions, but i can't figure out how to do this. I have my MainActivity with this code:

```java
  MyBroadcastReceiver broad = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
          broad.onReceive(context, new Intent("api6.intent.action.TRANSACTION_COMPLETED"));
```

Then in MyBroadcastReceiver, a class apart from the main, i have:

```java
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intents.ACTION_TRANSACTION_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                String txid = String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().get(Intents.INTENT_EXTRAS_TRANSACTION_ID));
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I need the String txid in MainActivity just after this line:

```java
         broad.onReceive(context, new Intent("api6.intent.action.TRANSACTION_COMPLETED"));
```

Comment: check the informal answer below,

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve in lot of ways, either by writing the broadcast class inside MainActivity class  or use an interface, implement it inside MainActivity

Eg

`MA extends AppCompat implements AnInterface{`

```
onCreate(){

broadcast = new YourBroadcastClass(this);
}

@override
public void interfaceMethod(String value){
}
```

and inside your broadcast class constructor

```
> AndInterface interface; MyBroad(AnInterface interface){ this.interface
> = interface; }
> 
> and onReceive(){ interface.interfaceMethod("whatever you wanna send")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it a lot, but doesn't work. I get this error: MyBroadcastReceiver> has no zero argument constructor